# accessing associations within before_add callback in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails 3.2 I have been looking for a way to traverse the associations of an object within the before_add callback.

So basically my use case is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :comments, :before_add => :set_owner_id
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting
end

def set_owner_id(child)
  child.owner_id = <<<THE USER ID for @user >>>
end
```

and I am creating a comment within the context of a user:

```
@user.meetings.first.comments.create
```

How do I traverse the associations from within the before_add callback to discover the id of @user? I want to set this at model level. I have been looking at proxy_association, but I may be missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: its also implossible to know from a meeting which user you are looking at so that kind of makes traversing hard. You cant say, self.metting.user because user has and belongs to many meetings meaning you can get a specific user from a meeting without knowing the id.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create the comment in the context of the meeting, no? Either way, you should handle this in the controller since you'll have no access to @user in your model.

```
@comment = Meeting.find(id).comments.create(owner_id: @user, ... )
```

But if you insist on your way, do this:

```
@comment = @user.meetings.first.comments.create(owner_id: @user.id)
```

Comment: My question is with regard to the model layer. Obviously if I wanted to I could set these parameters from the relevant controllers, but this does not deal with my question (association traversal within the before_add callback).

Comment: @iOn models don't know about your session, so they dont know about `@user`. This is intentional decoupling of Data Layer from Presentation Applicaiton layer. Your session exists in the view and the controller but never the model.

Comment: I know this. Please see the actual question.

Comment: ... and technically that is not actually true. For instance defining class instance variables (in the model layer) for multi tenancy. Anyway, I am looking for answers as to the use of proxy_association and related methods, nothing more.